# Почему пишется мягкий знак в названии молдавского села Бубуечь?

Tags: орфография

Вот ссылка: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C
Есть такое село в Молдавии.

С другой стороны, вот правила употребления мягкого знака после шипящих:

> § 75. После шипящих (ж, ч, ш, щ) буква ь пишется только в следующих
> случаях:
>
> 1. На конце существительных женского рода в им. и вин. пад. ед. ч., например: рожь, ночь, мышь.
> 2. В окончании 2-го лица ед. ч. настоящего и будущего времени глагола после конечного ш, например: несёшь – несёшься, носишь – носишься,
>    примешь – примешься.
> 3. На конце глагола в ед. ч. повелительного наклонения, причем буква ь сохраняется и перед -ся, например: мажь – мажься; спрячь – спрячься;
>    ешь.
> 4. Во множ. ч. повелительного наклонения перед -те, -тесь, например: мажьте – мажьтесь; спрячьте – спрячьтесь; ешьте.
> 5. На конце глагола в неопределённой форме, причем буква ь пишется и перед -ся, например: стричь, стричься.
> 6. Во всех наречиях после конечных ш и ч, например: сплошь, вскачь, прочь, а также в наречии настежь.
> 7. На конце частиц: вишь, бишь, лишь, ишь.

http://n-t.ru/ac/56/ob01.htm

Вопрос: почему название села Бубуечь пишется с мягкий знаком? Я не верю, что это имя существительное третьего склонения. Гордимся нашей Бубуечью? Между Кишинёвом и Бубуечью? Я сам живу в Молдавии (Молдове, если хотите). Ни разу не слышал, чтобы так говорили. Так что я уверен, что это не существительное третьего склонения.

Comment: Ни тот факт, что вы не верите, ни даже тот факт, что вы ни разу не слышали, не значит, что это точно не так. Вот в интернете например сразу находится - "Предлагаем Вам ознакомиться с подробной картой Бубуечи с улицами и номерами домов." Большинство назавани на ч пишутся с мягким знаком - например Керчь

Comment: @shabunc В принципе, ваш пример с «картой Бубуечи» может означать как третье склонение, так и несклоняемую транскрипцию официального румынского названия (Bubuieci)

Comment: "Исторически сложилось." Один грамотей написал, другие скопипастили. Лингвисты за голову схватились, да поздно. Так, например, никому не мешает жить Малая Уторгош: https://yandex.ru/maps/geo/derevnya_malaya_utorgosh/53128665/?ll=29.924710%2C58.264611&z=14

Comment: Nitpick: с мягки*м* знаком...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правописание названий не имеет никакого отношения к склонениям в русском языке.

Русские варианты названий молдавских топонимов формировались в соответствии с правилами транслитерации: они отражают русское правописание, которое наиболее похоже на исходное молдавское произношение.

В частности, безударное *ci* на конце слов транслитерируется в *чь*. Потому и Бубуечь (Bubuieci).

Comment: So why is it transliterated into *ч* (without *ь*) in Tecuci and Novaci?

Comment: no argument here, as I don't speak either. Is the *ci* at the end of Tecuci and Novaci pronounced any differently from *ci* at the end of Bubuieci?

Comment: *Правописание названий не имеет никакого отношения к склонениям в русском языке* - this one is plain wrong. If you put *ь* after the final sibilant in a Russian word, you make it feminine, period. This is just how orthography works. If you have a loanword ending in *-ч* you first need to decide whether you want it masculine or feminine, and only then write it accordingly.

Comment: sure, but the moment it starts being used in Russian speech it becomes a Russian word. It's pronounced using Russian phonetics, declines according to Russian paradigms and is written down using Russian orthography. It ends in *-ч(ь)*. Before you are able to write it down, you need to decide if it declines as masculine or feminine, or does not decline at all. You have to decide where you want it as *Бубуечью* or *Бубуечем* or *селом Бубуечь* in sg. inst. Only then, and not before, you can write it down: with *ь*, without *ь* or either way. The gender comes first, and orthography later.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: почему название села Бубуечь пишется с мягкий знаком?

Because whoever was making the decision on the gender of this name in Russian, wanted it to be feminine.

It they wanted it to be masculine, they would have dropped the *ь* at the end, like they did with *[Текуч](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87)* and *[Новач](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87)*.

I don't speak Moldovan and I'm not familiar with the actual usage of this word in Russian-speaking community, so I can't judge if that's a good decision or a bad decision.